# How to make sure that a shape has straight corners

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm looking for a way to draw a shape on an image, get the coordinates, then make minor corrections to have a perfect square or diamond.

I have a floor plan and i'm trying to highlight certain areas. Since i'm drawing over the image, i can't always get it a perfect shape and manual corrections takes time.

I would like to draw over the image, then pass it to a functiton which makes sure that each angles are 90 degrees, or it fixes the coordinates. The shape is always gonna be a square or a rectangle. All I want are the corrected coordinates so they can be saved in a file.

Here's a sample of the image i'm working with, along with one location:
var loc6 = [{x:711, y:596}, {x:787, y:595}, {x:784, y:641}, {x:711, y:641}];

https://imagebin.ca/v/2zjcnTJCRL2n

Math isn't my biggest asset, i've got the function below, but it only works to make a perfect square on squares, and messes up diamonds.

```
function fixRectangle(coords){
    var precision = 8;
    if(coords[0].y - coords[1].y < precision){
        coords[0].y = coords[1].y;
    }

    if(coords[1].x - coords[0].x < precision){
        coords[0].x = coords[1].x;
    }

    if(coords[2].y - coords[3].y < precision){
        coords[2].y = coords[3].y;
    }

    if(coords[2].x - coords[3].x < precision){
        coords[2].x = coords[3].x;
    }

    return coords;
}
```

(I do use jquery in case it is required)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Why exactly would jQuery be necessary here?

Comment: Maybe there's an helper function? Just giving all the facts.

Comment: You would probably do a little bit better using html5 canvas for something like this. It will give you access to the individual pixels for examination, and you can draw onto the image pretty easily. As far as making sure the lines are straight and the angles are 90 degrees, I don't think there is a simple automated solution. Pattern recognition is its own discipline in Mathematics.

Comment: Why not have the interface only allow to draw and rotate rectangles?  That would save you having to correct them.  Simply click drag until the rectangle is the right size, and then rotate it into position.  Telling the difference between a slightly rotated rectangle and a not-quite square rectangle in your code will be impossible.